# Verb after "than"

Tags: grammar

Just spotted out the following sentence from a museum's website. I don't understand why we can directly put the verb "visit" after "than" - in my understanding, we need to put a noun or gerund after "than". Also what is the subject of the verb "visit"?

From touring exhibitions to creative collaborations, our partnership work across the UK brings our collections to a much wider audience **than** can physically **visit** our museums.

Source: https://www.nms.ac.uk/about-us/what-we-do/

Comment: The subject is  *the much wider “audience”*.

Comment: The subject of _visit_ is _a much wider audience_. This (as shown by the presence of _than_) is a comparative sentence, and they are known to have odd syntax rules, peculiar to themselves; after all, comparisons involve slicing up two measure clauses to pick out and categorize the difference between them. That's industrial-strength syntax.

Comment: See here for similar usages: “*a typical client will raise more issues than can be handled in a therapy session*”. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22than+can%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1988,cd_max:2008&pccc=1

Comment: Got it! Thank you user070221 and John!